# How can I write multi class in a div with tab autocomplete WebStorm?

Tags: html, webstorm

In WebStorm if I write this `div.class` and after I click <kbd>Tab</kbd> it is replaced with this code `<div class="class"`

How can I write multiple classes in a `div` with this shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Emmet (see [official site](https://docs.emmet.io/))

So you target is to get `<div class="class1 class2"></div>`?

If so just keep writing classes via dots: `div.class1.class2`.

P.S. Since `div` is a default tag, it can be omitted and `.class1.class2` will provide the same result.